# How to make an alias of a DataFrame attribute during the instantiation?

Tags: python, pandas

To simplify my problem, let's consider this simple class.

```
import pandas as pd

class Report:
    
    def __init__(self, t=pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2]}), n=None):
        self.name = n
        self.table_as_df = t
        
        _df = self.table_as_df
        
        _df = _df.rename(columns={'col1': 'col2'}) \
                   .assign(col3=['A', 'B']) \
                   .transpose()
               
report = Report().table_as_df
```

I made an alias for `self.table_as_df` to avoid repeating it.

Now the problem is that `print(report)` gives me only one column :

```
   col1
0     1
1     2
```

I feel like we need to use `inplace=True` but not all functions have it. I would like to use chain assignment.

Here is my expected output :

```
      0  1
col2  1  2
col3  A  B
```

Do you guys have a solution for my problem ? Also, can you suggest a better design for my class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution can be using a `@property`:

```py
import pandas as pd


class Report:
    def __init__(self, t=None, n=None):
        if t is None:
            t = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 2]})

        self.name = n
        self._df = t
        self._df = (
            self._df.rename(columns={"col1": "col2"})
            .assign(col3=["A", "B"])
            .transpose()
        )

    @property
    def table_as_df(self):
        return self._df


report = Report().table_as_df
print(report)
```

Prints:

```
      0  1
col2  1  2
col3  A  B
```